# how do I redirect a subdomain to another subdomain where query string must remain intact

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have subdomain http://example.website.com

and I need it to redirect to another subdomain http://othersite.website.com?os_username=admin&os_password=1234

I need the query string (with un and pw) to remain intact upon the site being redirected.

Right now the query string drops off and you're taken to the general login page.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: How are you doing your current redirect?

Comment: .htaccess. I have a domain canonicalization rule to change www. to domain without www. I take it I need to add a new rule to the .htaccess file, is that correct? If so I would need to know the rule specifically and how to keep that query string intact.

Comment: it's being hosted on a Linux server

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dealing with username and passwords, why not just post the information on the server, set the cookie, then redirect the user after the cookie has been set?

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this if you are using .htaccess:

`RewriteEngine On`

`# Map http://example.website.com to http://othersite.website.com?os_username=admin&os_password=1234`

`RewriteRule ^$ http://othersite.website.com?os_username=admin&os_password=1234 [L]`

Although I don't think it will work across a different domain I have yet to test it since I am at work. Usually I use it like so:

`RewriteEngine On`

`# Map http://www.website.com to /index

RewriteRule ^$ /index [L]`

That will redirect www.website.com to www.website.com/index. I hope that helps.

Comment: the string isn't keeping in the redirect, but I certainly appreciate you taking the time to answer.